# 'No symbols have been loaded' error when remote debugging Azure Web App

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm building a web service against .NET 4.6.1 on ASP.NET Core. Locally it has been fine - I can debug no issues and everything works. Recently I took to getting it up online as an Azure Web App, which also works no problems now. The service loads and runs fine.

However I cannot remote debug it. When I do try to remote debug it, although it attaches no problems none of the break points fire and they turn hollow with the error `No symbols have been loaded for this document`.

I have tried and/or confirmed:

1. It is a debug build being pushed to a slot set to debug on VS 2015.
2. I've tried downgrading .NET to 4.6.
3. I've wiped out the Web App entirely and made a new one from scratch.
4. All extensions in VS 2015 are up to date.
5. In the VS Modules window, no modules or symbols have been loaded.
6. I have confirmed there is a PDB file present next to the app executable.
7. I have tried unchecking the "Just my code" checkbox in VS.
8. The Web App is configured for x64.
9. I have tried it on a completely different PC.

My web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true" />
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" stdoutLogEnabled="false" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: have you ever resolved this?

Comment: Nope! Even had support assist to a degree. Just seems like a very flaky service. Or was. I haven't tried in a month or two.